# Why is Heroku telling me "Your app has no databases" when it clearly does?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, migration

I know the subject of migrating Heroku databases has lots of documentation but I have yet to find my answer, and nobody seems to be mentioning the error I'm getting.

I developed my app using the basic/free version of Heroku, where I get my two random dictionary words and a number.  I've got a Rails app running in this instance, populated with data.  It's what I've used to demo to management.

My company now has paid space on Heroku, including Postgres.  I've gotten my application deployed to this new space, including an empty Postgres database (I've run migrations), and now I would like to move my data over from the free/shared space, to my paid space.

I believe this is the page of directions I'm supposed to be following:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres

But when I get to this step:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -a [my_app]
```

I get the error in my question, "Your app has no databases."  I've done the necessary steps, added the pgbackups add-on and so forth.  If I execute this command against my newly created paid app (with the empty database), it works fine.  But running it for my old/free/shared-db version gets the error.

I get that it does not have a paid database, no.  If I go to http://postgres.heroku.com it doesn't even show up.  But I've got data living in a database somewhere in Heroku world, and I'd like to get at it.  The documentation does lead me to believe that these are the instructions for getting off the 5mb shared space, which is what I'm on.

Comment: Think I found it.  Updated my heroku client and now it warned me that I was not using the SHARED_DATABASE option.  Adding this got me past this step.

Comment: Sounds like you got it figured out! For future reference... each app is attached to a database through a config variable. Yours might have been blank or pointing towards a non-existant database. You can see more about config vars here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't take into account some corner cases on an update I wrote for the client. A later version fixed it as I think you figured out. Sorry.

Comment: Accepted for confirming that the problem was related to the version of the heroku client.